# Portable library to play samples on individual 5.1 channels with C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, audio, openal

I'm looking for a free, portable C or C++ library which allows me to play mono sound samples on specific channels in a 5.1 setup. For example the sound should be played with the left front speaker whereby all other speakers remain silent. Is there any library capable of doing this?

I had a look at OpenAL. However, I can only specify the position from which the sound should come, but it seems to me that I cannot say something like "use only the front left channel to play this sound".

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: The other ones I'm aware of are irrKlang and fmod, but I think they are both positional as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I had a look at OpenAL. However, I can only specify the position from which the sound should come, but it seems to me that I cannot say something like "use only the front left channel to play this sound".

I don't think this is quite true.  I think you can do it with OpenAL, although it's not trivial.  OpenAL only does the positional stuff if you feed it `mono` format data.  If you give it stereo or higher, it plays the data the way it was provided.  However, you're only guaranteed stereo support.  You'll need to check to see if the 5.1 channel format extension is available on your system (AL_FORMAT_51CHN16).  If so, then, I think that you feed your sound to the channel you want and feed zeroes to all the others channels when you buffer the samples.  Note that you need hardware support for this on the sound card.  A "generic software" device won't cut it.

See [this discussion](http://opensource.creative.com/pipermail/openal/2009-April/011590.html) from the OpenAL mailing list.

Alternatively, I think that [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com) is Open, cross-platform, and supports multiple channel output.  You do still have to interleave the data so that if you're sending a sound to a single channel, you have to send zeroes to all the others.  You'll also still need to do some checking when opening a stream on a device to make sure the device supports 6 channels of output.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I used [RTAudio](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/). But I cannot say if this lib can do what you want to archive, but maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://fmod.org could do the trick too

Answer (score 0):

I use the **BASS Audio Library** http://www.un4seen.com for all my audio, sound and music projects. I am very happy with it.

> BASS is an audio library to provide developers with powerful and efficient sample, stream (MP3, MP2, MP1, OGG, WAV, AIFF, custom generated, and more via add-ons), MOD music (XM, IT, S3M, MOD, MTM, UMX), MO3 music (MP3/OGG compressed MODs), and recording functions. All in a tiny DLL, under 100KB* in size. C/C++, Delphi, Visual Basic, MASM, .Net and other APIs are available. BASS is available for the Windows, Mac, Win64, WinCE, Linux, and iOS platforms.

I have never used it to play different samples in a 5.1 configuration. But, according their own documentation, it should be possible.

> **Main features**
>
> - **Samples** Support for WAV/AIFF/MP3/MP2/MP1/OGG and custom generated samples
> - **Sample streams** Stream any sample data in 8/16/32 bit, with both "push" and "pull" systems. **File streams** MP3/MP2/MP1/OGG/WAV/AIFF file streaming. **Internet file streaming**. Stream data from HTTP and FTP servers (inc. Shoutcast, Icecast & Icecast2), with IDN and proxy server support and adjustable buffering. ** Custom file streaming ** Stream data from anywhere using any delivery method, with both "push" and "pull" systems
> - **Multi-channel** Support for more than plain stereo, including multi-channel OGG/WAV/AIFF files
>
> ...
>
> - **Multiple outputs** Simultaneously use multiple soundcards, and move channels between them
> - **Speaker assignment** Assign streams and MOD musics to specific speakers to take advantage of hardware capable of more than plain stereo (up to 4 separate stereo outputs with a 7.1 soundcard)
> - **3D sound** Play samples/streams/musics in any 3D position
>
> **Licensing**
>
> BASS is free for non-commercial use. If you are a non-commercial entity (eg. an individual) and you are not making any money from your product (through sales, advertising, etc), then you can use BASS in it for free. Otherwise, one of the following licences will be required.